# HTML5 CSS3 TableTag

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here is the CSS file in which i applied some border for the whole table.

```
#tableCount
{
border: 1px solid gray;
margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Here is the HTML file as below:

```
<table id="tableCount" style="width: 30%; height: 50%;" class="table table-striped" [mfData]="data | dataFilter : filterQuery" #mf="mfDataTable"
                   [mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage" [(mfSortBy)]="sortBy" [(mfSortOrder)]="sortOrder">
                <thead>
                    <tr id="t1">
                        <td colspan="3" style="color:white; width: 10%;">Status</td>
                        <td style="text-align:right;">

                            <button id="buttons" (click)="addRow()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                            <span style="color:black;" title="Add Row" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 10%">S.No.</th>
                  <th style="width: 10%; color:white;">
                          <mfDefaultSorter by="status">Status</mfDefaultSorter>
                        </th>
                        <th style="width: 10%"></th>
                        <th style="width: 10%"></th>
                 </tr>
         </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data; let i=index">
                        <td>
                            {{i+1}}
                      </td>
                   <td>{{item.status}}</td>
                       <td></td>
                        <td style="text-align:right;">
                      <button id="buttons" (click)="editRow()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                            <span style="color:dark grey;" title="Edit Row" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                            </button>
             <button id="buttons" (click)="deleteRow(i)" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                            <span style="color:red;" title="Delete Row" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                            </button>
                        </td></tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr style="width: 10%;">
                        <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="5">
                           <input id="footer" type="button" value="Submit"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

[image]

Why the border is not being applied from the right side, i have tried to do in different way. Stuck here.

Any help appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your border is being overlapped by elements in your tbody / thead. One hotfix could be to add border to each tr element.

Comment: @ManmeetS.Oberoi Still Its not working , I added border to every tr element

Answer (score 0):

Reffer this code might be helpfull to solve your problem
Here is the CSS file

```
table.roundedCorners { 
  border: 1px solid DarkOrange;
  border-radius: 13px; 
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table.roundedCorners td, 
table.roundedCorners th { 
  border-bottom: 1px solid DarkOrange;
  padding: 10px; 
}

table.roundedCorners tr:last-child > td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Here is the HTML file as below:

```
<table class="roundedCorners">
  <tr>
    <th>Table Header</th>
    <th>Table Header</th>
    <th>Table Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```